# debugging video encoding errors (stream analyzer)

Tags: debugging, stream, video-encoding, analyzer

I create videos programmatically via FFMPEG's API. The resulting files have issues with choppy playback, flickering, etc.

Are there any tools that can analyze audio/video for encoding errors? Or at least, dump the info for each frame (ie. PTS, frame type, etc).

Any other suggestions on troubleshooting this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for MPEG stream analyzer and miss the "stream analyzer" keyword for google query ;) There are many solutions, I do not have much experience (I have used some during my university classes). A few examples I know of include:

- [TSReader](http://www.tsreader.com/tsreader/index.html)
- [Manzanita TSA](http://www.manzanitasystems.com/products/transport-stream-analyzer.html)
- [MPEG-2 TS packet analyser](http://www.pjdaniel.org.uk/mpeg/index.php)

I do not know whether there is complex solution available for commercial purposes for free. As I said, I may be mistaken due to my limited contact with such software, but you can check above stated and google for more.